# $\aleph_{0} \times c=c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering if my proof for the question: $\aleph_{0} \times c=c$ is correct.
$$\\
\exists \: f:\mathbb{N} \times (0,1) \:\to \:(0,1)\\
\owns \:(n,x) \:\to 0.nx_{1}x_{2}x_{3}....\\
card\mathbb{N} \times card(0,1) \le card(0,1) \\
\\
\exists g: (0,1) \to \mathbb{N} \times (0,1) \\
\owns x \:\to \:(n,x), \:(x=0.x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}...) \\
card (0,1)\: \le \:card\mathbb{N} x card(0,1) \\$$

$\therefore \: \aleph_{0}\times\:c=c$

Answer (score 3):

The idea of finding injections $f:\Bbb N\times(0,1)\to(0,1)$ and $g:(0,1)\to\Bbb N(0,1)$ is fine, but the execution has problems.

Assuming that by $0.nx_1x_2x_3\ldots$ you mean the decimal expansion whose first digits to the right of the decimal point are the digits of $n$ in its usual decimal representation, your function $f$ is not injective: it sends $\left\langle n,\frac19\right\rangle$ to $\frac19=0.1111\ldots$ for every $n\in\{1,11,111,1111,\ldots\}$. Your $g$ is not actually defined: for which value of $n\in\Bbb N$ is $g(0.1)$ equal to $\langle n,0.1\rangle$, for instance?

The latter problem is easy to fix: just let $g(x)=\langle 1,x\rangle$, for instance. Here’s a suggestion for fixing the former problem. You know that $|\Bbb R|=|(0,1)|=\mathfrak{c}$, so instead of mapping $\mathscr{N}\times(0,1)$ injectively into $(0,1)$, you could map it injectively into $\Bbb R$: how about letting $f$ send $\langle n,x\rangle\in\Bbb N\times(0,1)$ to $n+x\in\Bbb R$? You shouldn’t have any trouble showing that this map is an injection.